# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')

Tags: react-native, undefined

I am trying to use react-native-image-picker, but stuck here, it always shows the error as on the below photo:

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')

Is there anyone who had this problem?

[image]

Comment: You need to share some code for people to be able to help you with this. Eg. show us how you import `ImagePickerManager` and how/where you are calling `showImagePicker`.

Comment: Thank you, and I am sorry I am the new one here. The problem has been fixed. So happy

Comment: @Sookie and how did you fix it?

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue here !

Answer (score 3):

I had met it too. After a few hours, I find a solution to it.

Install
$npm install react-native-image-picker@latest --save
Automatic Installation
React Native >= 0.29 $react-native link
React Native < 0.29 $rnpm link

https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/README.md
This document is not up-to-date.

Using the above command, you can get the latest one. Then you can follow the README.md to use it.
That is my way to solve it.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

This message is basically saying that the native side of your app is not fully linked with the library.

Be sure to add:

- iOS : `libRNImagePicker.a` to your app (`XCode => Build phases => Link Binary with Libraries => +, then select the right file`)
- Android : `compile project(':react-native-image-picker')` to your `build.gradle` file

Comment: I am unable to find `libRNImagePIcker.a` among to options. Do I have to download it from somewhere?