# React Native Image Picker: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I followed the Readme from [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker%22React-native-image-picker%22) with both manual and automatic linking (tried both separately).

When I launch simulator from terminal using `react-native run-ios` I get the error. When launching from Xcode it works fine, I can access the CameraRoll picker no problem.

Here are the versions I'm using:

`"react-native": "0.43.3",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.3",`

I saw a similar thread here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018381/undefined-is-not-an-objectevaluating-imagepickermanager-showimagepicker) and it seems I'm not the only one having this issue.

Thank you for helping.

The full error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')

showImagePicker
    index.js:28:30
selectPhotoTapped
    CamPick.js:31:32
touchableHandlePress
    TouchableOpacity.js:126:45
_performSideEffectsForTransition
    Touchable.js:746:34
_receiveSignal
    Touchable.js:664:44
touchableHandleResponderRelease
    Touchable.js:433:24
invokeGuardedCallback
    ReactErrorUtils.js:30:9
executeDispatch
    EventPluginUtils.js:99:42
executeDispatchesInOrder
    EventPluginUtils.js:127:20
executeDispatchesAndRelease
    EventPluginHub.js:37:46
forEachAccumulated
    forEachAccumulated.js:30:16
processEventQueue
    EventPluginHub.js:227:8
runEventQueueInBatch
    ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:18:35
handleTopLevel
    ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:38:25
<unknown>
    ReactNativeEventEmitter.js:113:8
perform
    Transaction.js:149:24
batchedUpdatesWithControlledComponents
    ReactGenericBatching.js:51:26
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent
    ReactNativeEventEmitter.js:111:40
receiveTouches
    ReactNativeEventEmitter.js:200:8
__callFunction
    MessageQueue.js:244:47
<unknown>
    MessageQueue.js:108:26
guard
    MessageQueue.js:46:4
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    MessageQueue.js:107:10
```

Comment: Did you do: `var ImagePickerManager = require('react-native-image-picker');` ?

Comment: I used the one from the example ```import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';``` I just tried your version and I get the same error

Comment: Ok , so change it like: `import ImagePickerManager from 'react-native-image-picker';`

Comment: I get the same error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed that Xcode was not linking the files properly, the trick who worked for me was to:

1. Open Xcode project 'MainProject.xcodeproj'
2. Under MainProject under Libraries I would go find RNImagePicker.xcodeproj
3. Under RNImagePicker.xcodeproj I would right click and delete both files ImagePickerManager.h and ImagePickerManager.m
4. Right click on RNImagePicker.xocdeproj to 'Add files to ...' and then would select both files from 'node_modules/react-native-maps/ios/ImagePickerManager.h and ImagePickerManganer.m'

Hope it helps somebody who might have the same problem ;)

Comment: Hi. My app does not have react-native-maps folder. Should I install it or I miss anything?